# Error when trying run loop with multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a function in a loop many times using parallel multiprocessing.

When I run this simple code:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def heavy_processing(number):
    time.sleep(0.05)  # simulate a long-running operation
    output = number + 1
    return output

with Pool(4) as p:
    numbers = list(range(0, 1000))    
    results = p.map(heavy_processing, numbers)
```

I get the following error:

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 367, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'heavy_processing' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I'm not sure why, since I pretty much pulling this example straight from other sources. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are you running under an IDE such as Jupyter Notebook? If so, your *worker function*, `heavy_processing`, needs to be imported by the script rather than being a function defined within the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the multiprocessing code always under the     `if __name__ == '__main__':` or
else it doesn't work. If you see the last line of your cmd you can see AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'heavy_processing' on <module '**main**' (built-in)> which specifies that it couldn't find 'heavy_processing' on '**main**'

**Full Code**

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def heavy_processing(number):
    time.sleep(0.05)  # simulate a long-running operation
    output = number + 1
    print(output)
    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as p:
        numbers = list(range(0, 1000))
        results = p.map(heavy_processing, numbers)
```

**Output**

```
1
64
127
190
2  
65 
128
191
3
66
129
192
4
67
130
193
5
68
131
194
6
69
132
195
7
70
133
196
8
71
134
197
9
72
135
198
10
73
136
199
11
74
137
200
75
12
138
201
76
13
139
202
77
14
140
203
78
15
141
204
79
16
142
205
17
80
143
206
18
81
144
207
19
82
145
208
20
83
146
209
21
84
147
210
22
85
148
211
23
86
149
212
24
87
150
213
25
88
151
214
26
89
152
215
90
27
153
216
91
28
154
217
92
29
155
218
30
93
156
219
31
94
157
220
95
32
158
221
33
96
159
222
97
34
160
223
98
35
161
224
99
36
162
225
100
37
163
226
101
38
164
227
102
39
165
228
103
40
166
229
104
41
167
230
105
42
168
231
106
43
169
232
107
44
170
233
108
45
171
234
109
46
172
235
110
47
173
236
111
48
174
237
112
49
175
238
113
50
176
239
114
51
177
240
52
115
178
241
53
116
179
242
117
54
180
243
55
118
181
244
56
119
182
245
57
120
183
246
121
58
184
247
122
59
185
248
123
60
186
249
124
61
187
250
125
62
188
251
126
63
189
252
253
316
379
442
254
317
380
443
255
318
381
444
256
319
382
445
257
320
383
446
258
321
384
447
259
322
385
448
260
323
386
449
261
324
387
450
262
325
388
451
263
326
389
452
264
327
390
453
265
328
391
454
266
329
392
455
267
330
393
456
268
331
394
457
269
332
395
458
270
333
396
459
271
334
397
460
272
335
398
461
273
336
399
462
274
337
400
463
275
338
401
464
276
339
402
465
277
340
403
466
278
341
404
467
279
342
405
280
468
343
406
281
469
344
407
470
282
345
408
471
283
346
409
472
284
347
410
473
285
348
411
474
286
349
412
475
287
350
413
476
288
351
414
477
289
352
415
290
478
353
416
479
291
354
417
480
292
355
418
293
481
356
419
294
482
357
420
295
483
358
421
296
484
359
422
297
485
360
423
298
486
361
424
299
487
362
425
300
488
363
426
301
489
364
427
302
490
365
428
303
491
366
429
304
492
367
430
305
493
368
431
306
494
369
432
307
495
370
433
308
496
371
434
309
497
372
435
310
498
373
436
311
499
374
437
312
500
375
438
313
501
376
439
314
502
377
440
315
503
378
441
505
504
568
631
506
694
569
632
507
695
570
633
508
696
571
634
509
697
572
635
510
698
573
636
511
699
574
637
512
700
575
638
513
701
576
639
514
702
577
640
515
703
578
516
704
641
579
517
705
642
580
518
706
643
581
519
707
644
582
520
708
645
583
521
709
646
584
522
710
647
585
523
711
648
586
524
712
649
587
525
650
713
588
526
651
714
589
527
715
652
590
528
716
653
591
529
717
654
592
530
718
655
593
531
719
656
594
532
720
657
595
721
533
658
596
534
722
659
597
535
723
660
598
536
724
661
599
537
725
662
600
538
726
663
601
539
727
664
602
540
728
665
603
541
729
666
604
542
730
667
605
543
731
668
606
544
732
669
607
545
733
670
608
546
734
671
609
547
735
672
610
548
736
673
611
549
737
674
612
550
738
675
613
551
739
676
614
552
740
677
615
553
741
678
616
554
742
679
617
555
743
680
618
556
744
681
619
557
745
682
620
558
746
683
621
559
747
684
622
560
748
685
623
561
749
686
624
562
750
687
625
563
751
688
626
564
752
689
627
565
753
690
628
566
754
691
629
567
755
692
630
757
756
693
820
758
883
946
821
759
884
947
822
760
885
948
823
761
886
949
824
762
887
950
825
763
888
951
826
764
889
952
827
765
890
953
828
766
891
954
829
767
892
955
830
768
893
956
831
769
894
957
832
770
895
958
833
771
896
959
834
772
897
960
835
773
898
961
836
774
899
962
837
775
900
963
838
776
901
964
839
777
902
965
840
778
903
966
841
779
904
967
842
780
905
968
843
781
906
969
844
782
907
970
845
783
908
971
846
784
909
972
847
785
910
973
848
786
911
974
849
787
912
975
850
788
913
976
851
789
914
977
852
790
915
978
853
791
916
979
854
792
917
980
855
793
918
981
856
794
919
982
857
795
920
983
858
796
921
984
859
797
922
985
860
798
923
986
861
799
924
987
862
800
925
988
863
801
926
989
864
802
927
990
865
803
928
991
866
804
929
992
867
805
930
993
868
806
931
994
869
807
932
995
870
808
933
996
871
809
934
997
872
810
935
998
873
811
936
999
874
812
937
1000
875
813
938
876
814
939
877
815
940
878
816
941
879
817
942
880
818
943
881
819
944
882
945
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)